# C# List<List<T>> Sort

Tags: c#, linq

How can I sort a list of list?

```
persons.OrderBy(p => p.rate).ToList();
```

The list of list (`persons`) is declared like this:

```
public class Persons : List<Person> { }
```

When I'm trying to run the first statement I get an error:

> Cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'Persons'

Is there a way to do this using LINQ?

Comment: That error sounds like the result of a bad assignment. On its own your first statement won't produce a compiler error.

Comment: @AdamKing, it's a class definition, what do you think is wrong with it

Comment: if you are trying to do `persons = persons.OrderBy(p => p.rate).ToList();` **ToList** will return you `List<Person>` and its not the same thing with `Persons` class. you can cast `Persons` as `List<Person>` but you cant cast `List<Person>` to `Persons`

Comment: @ÖzgürKara You should expound upon that idea and post it as an answer.

Comment: I don't understand why people have down-voted this.

Comment: @DanielMcNulty Is was pretty murky initially and had receive at least one down-vote before I made my edit.

Comment: Ahh right, missed the 'edited', my fault.

Comment: Any reason for going down this garden path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achive it with that statement:

```
var persons = new Persons ();
persons.AddRange(persons.OrderBy(p => p.rate));
```

Comment: Won't that duplicate all of the items in the list?

Comment: it wont because you declare it as new object

Comment: I thought `Person` would contain a property `rate` and not `Persons`.

Comment: With this you'll either always end up with an empty list, because you don't store the reference to the old list (the one with the items) anywhere or (if there's a `...` missing between those two statements) duplicate the list entries every time you try to sort them.

Answer (score 5):

Just because it inherits from a list doesn't mean you can use it like one.

Remember for everything else to see it as a list use `interfaces` (**[IList<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx)**). Then methods depending on `IEnumerable`, `IList`, `ICollection`, etc. can see that it's something it can deal with.

Otherwise, whose to say your [`Add()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/63ywd54z.aspx) (As defined by `IList`) method isn't named `AddPerson` in your class?

Comment: if it would declared like that persons : IList<Person> methods that return IList could still deal with this , when i tests it thats didnt worked

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order all persons in all lists and huddle up them into one list:

```
var persons = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Persons>();
var trio = new Persons() { new Person(7), new Person(3), new Person(8) };
var pair = new Persons() { new Person(1), new Person(2) };
persons.Add(trio);
persons.Add(pair);

var ordered = persons.SelectMany(p => p).OrderBy(p => p.rate).ToList();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To achieve a `SortBy` behavior, you have to follow these three easy steps:

1. Store the old items (a. by storing the reference to the old list | b. by copying all entries of the old list into a new one)
2. Create an empty instance of your container class (a. by creating a new object of the needed type | b. by clearing the old list)
3. Fill your empty list with the entries while ordering them as you desire.

This little extension method should do the Trick:

```
public static void SortBy<TList, TItem, TOrder>(this TList source,
                                                Func<TItem, TOrder> sortFunc)
    where TList : List<TItem>
{
    var l = source.ToList();
    source.Clear();
    source.AddRange(l.OrderBy(sortFunc));
}
```